# What do you think you were doing? - infinitive/subjunctive form

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, infinitive

AFAIK "What do you think you were doing" could be expressed using either infinitive (more usual) or subjunctive forms in Italian. Would those be:

- Che cosa credi di stare facendo ?
- Cosa credi che stessi facendo ?

I am particulary in doubt if the infinitive form should use "stare facendo" or "fare".

Comment: In my experience it is more likely that  the second phrase means "what do you think that I were doing"

Comment: "Cosa credevi di fare?” would be the standard way. No “progressive form”.

Comment: Is it correct to use the "imperfetto" tense for a present event? The English sentence uses "think" in the present tense because the event of thinking occurs now, not in the past.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence *cosa credi che stessi facendo?* would be interpreted like *what do you think I was doing?*

Adding the subject pronoun would sound very heavy and “unitalian”: **cosa credi che tu stessi facendo?*, because a direct clause sharing the subject with the main proposition should have the verb at the infinitive (*di* + infinitive). The progressive form with the past infinitive is not used, nor it is used with the “passato remoto”.

It's quite possible that in informal speech the question could be *cosa credi che stavi facendo?* (there is some recent influence from English with respect to progressive forms), but the standard form is *cosa credevi di fare?*

Note that the usage of progressive forms differs between Italian and English; don't always try and keep English progressive forms.